# PHP (folder) File Listing in Alphabetical Order?

Tags: php, file, directory, alphabetized

I'm not sure how simple this would be, but I'm using a script which displays the files from a specific folder, however I'd like them to be displayed in alphabetical order, would it be hard to do this? Here's the code I'm using:

```
if ($handle = opendir($mainframe->getCfg( 'absolute_path' ) ."/images/store/")) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..")  {
                if (($file != "index.html")&&($file != "index.php")&&($file != "Thumbs.db")) {
                $strExt = end(explode(".", $file));
                    if ($strExt == 'jpg') {
                        $Link = 'index.php?option=com_shop&amp;task=deleteFile&amp;file[]='.$file;
                        $thelist .= '<tr class="row0"><td nowrap="nowrap"><a href="'.$Link.'">'.$file.'</a></td>'."\n";
                        $thelist .= '<td align="center" class="order"><a href="'.$Link.'" title="delete"><img src="/administrator/images/publish_x.png" width="16" height="16" alt="delete"></a></td></tr>'."\n";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle); 
    }   
    echo $thelist;
```

:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using `readdir` you could simply use `scandir` ([documentation](http://tw.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)) which sorts alphabetically by default.

The return value of `scandir` is an array instead of a string, so your code would have to be adjusted slightly, to iterate over the array instead of checking for the final `null` return value. Also, `scandir` takes a string with the directory path instead of a file handle as input, the new version would look something like this:

```
foreach(scandir($mainframe->getCfg( 'absolute_path' ) ."/images/store/") as $file) {
  // rest of the loop could remain unchanged
}
```

Comment: Found this answer while trying to solve same exact problem. Thanks! Worked well, and with less code!

Comment: This worked great. After reading the documentation I was even able to reverse the sorting order with `SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING` as a second argument to `scandir(...)`. Several other sorting constants were documented as well in the link provided.

Answer (score 4):

That code looks pretty messy. You can separate the directory traversing logic with the presentation. A much more concise version (in my opinion):

```
<?php

// Head of page
$it = new DirectoryIterator($mainframe->getCfg('absolute_path') . '/images/store/'));

foreach ($it as $file) {
    if (preg_match('#\.jpe?g$#', $file->getFilename()))
        $files[] = $file->getFilename();
}
sort($files);

// Further down
foreach ($files as $file)
    // display links to delete file.
?>
```

You don't even need to worry about opening or closing the handle, and since you're checking the filename with a regular expression, you don't need any of the explode or conditional checks.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)
It makes directory reading a snap as it returns an array that's easily sortable:

```
<?php
$files = glob("*.txt");
sort($files);
foreach ($files as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Joomla1.5 you should be using the defined constant **JPATH_BASE** instead of

```
$mainframe->getCfg( 'absolute_path' )
```

If this is a Joomla extension that you will distribute, don't use **scandir()** as it is PHP5 only.

The best thing to do is to use the Joomla API. It has a classes for directory and file access that is layered to do this over different networks and protocols. So the file system can be over FTP for example, and the classes can be extended for any network/protocol.

```
jimport( 'joomla.filesystem.folder' );
$files = JFolder::files(JPATH_BASE."/images/store/");
sort($files); 
foreach($files as $file) { 
   // do your filtering and other task
}
```

You can also pass a regular expression as the second parameter to JFolder::files() that filters the files you receive.

You also don't want to use URL literals like /administrator/ since they can be changed.
use the JURI methods like:

JURI::base();

If you want to make sure of the Joomla CSS classes in the tables, for:

```
'<tr class="row0">'
```

use:

```
'<tr class="row'.($i&1).'">'
```

where **$i** is the number of iterations. This gives you a sequence of alternating 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 1):

if we have PHP built in functions, always use it, they are faster.
use glob instead of traversing folders, if it fits for your needs.

$folder_names = array();
$folder_names = glob( '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR + GLOB_MARK + GLOB_NOSORT );

- returs everything in the current directory, use chdir() before calling it
  remove the GLOB_ONLYDIR to include files too ( *.* would be only files )
  GLOB_MARK is for adding a slash to folders names
  Remove GLOB_NOSORT not to sort  the array

Comment: Not always. If you have a standardized API, use that.

In this particular case, the code was written for the Joomla CMS. Thus it should use the Joomla API. 

Speed is rarely a concern in web development. Good design is.