# What order does php's glob function return pathnames in?

Tags: php

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/glob) for glob doesn't mention what order (if any) it returns the array of pathnames in, however, it does mention a flag that allows you to disable sorting.

> **GLOB_NOSORT** - Return files as they appear in the directory (no
> sorting)

How is the array sorted by `glob` when when the `GLOB_NOSORT` flag is not used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the list is sorted [**ASCIIbethical**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_order) in ascending order, i.e *A, B, C...Z, a, b, c...z, 0,1...9*. Its a copy of the libc `glob()`

Source http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_426.html

Also the PHP source C code for glob: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/89a9acea1f9d821a9805b3857bf4febbba08690d/win32/glob.c#L521

Comment: thanks, didn't want to rely on testing. the note about alphabetical sorting in libc is what i was looking for.

Comment: np, I did some research last night after you asked me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665648/php-how-to-generate-indexed-name-with-string-in-file-output/24665789#comment38239916_24665789 it *should* note the sorting order in the docs, just to clarify.

Comment: Ive requested an edit to the docs, GLOB_NOSORT - Return files as they appear in the directory (no sorting), By default, the list is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: According to the source pointed to in the answer, the order is actually **[ASCIIbethical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_order)**, and **ascending**. It's evident from the `qrsort` call right next to the line that Lawrence's link points to. It uses a comparator function based on `strcmp`, which simply compares character codes. There may be subtle differences between OSes in the ordering of locale-specific characters (depending on the encoding used by the OS), but the standard English subset is being sorted in the ASCII order (eg. uppercase letters before lowercase letters).

Comment: This answer is wrong. As  ksadowski said, sorting is ASCIIbethical, and ascending, like this : A, B, C...Z, a, b, c...z

Comment: @Chrysotribax updated

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that in my experience I am getting files ordered like this

```
Alpha.txt
Beta.txt
Zebra.txt
alpha.txt
beta.txt
zebra.txt
```

This is on linux

It would be best to have

```
Alpha.txt
alpha.txt
Beta.txt
beta.txt
Zebra.txt
zebra.txt
```