# PHP : how to process the files _alphabetically_ using DirectoryIterator?

Tags: php, file, directory, alphabetical, file-processing

[Using this way,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1095753/1188304) after the completion of DirectoryIterator cycle
you will get a list of filenames, and later you will be able to alphabetically sort it,
so that you can process each file with a filename from this list - in alphabetical order...

Now, what if, after the completion of DirectoryIterator cycle,
you need an **array** (alphabetically sorted by filename), that contains **not only the filename**,
**but also all the other file properties**, such as:

- *permissions*
- *owner*
- *time of creation*
- *size*
- *etc...*

The problem here is, you cant sort **before** the completion of DirectoryIterator cycle,
and **after it** you will not be able to access anything other than filenames from your  list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectoryIterator objects provide a simple way to access many of file properties.

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($dir as $fileInfo) {
    if ((!$fileInfo->isDot())&&($fileInfo->GetExtension() == "txt")) {
        /* You can access the file information inside this cycle */
        $octal_perms = substr(sprintf('%o', $fileInfo->getPerms()), -4);
        echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . " " . $octal_perms . "\n";
    }
}
```

If we need the **fileInfo** objects after the completion of DirectoryIterator cycle,
we will have to clone (copy) all these DirectoryIterator objects into a new array,
and then sort this array alphabetically by filename attribute of DirectoryIterator objects.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->getFilename(), $b->getFilename());
}

$dir = new DirectoryIterator($path);
foreach ($dir as $fileInfo) {
    if ((!$fileInfo->isDot())&&($fileInfo->GetExtension() == "txt")) {
        /* we need to clone a fileInfo object into array, not just assign it */
        $allFilesInfo[] = clone $fileInfo;
    }
}

/* Alphabetically sorting the array with DirectoryIterator objects, by filename */
usort($allFilesInfo, 'cmp');

foreach ($allFilesInfo as $fileInfo) {
    /* Everything is alphabetical here ;) */
    $octal_perms = substr(sprintf('%o', $fileInfo->getPerms()), -4);
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . " " . $octal_perms . "\n";
}
```

^^ In this last cycle, you can work with your files in alphabetical order,
while being able to access all their properties :)

**NOTE:** in case of crash, caused by "too many open files" error,
increase the max limit of open file descriptors per a process in your OS.
Related config files are depend on your OS, and usually they're stored in /etc

Comment: "Too many open files" should not be ignored. You are forgeting to free up/close resources if you get such an error. One SHOULD NOT simply raise the limit without understanding the cause of such an error.